# To pin the caption of the scrollable table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

Here is a table with pinned row and column. I'm trying to improve it by pinning the caption as well. I.e. when you scroll the table, the caption should not be scrolled - it should be visible permanently. Is it possible?

I already tried `caption-side: top-outside`, but:

- `top-outside` works in Firefox only. Instead, my target browser is Chrome.
- It seems it simply don't solve the task.

```css
.wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 500px;
}

caption, th, p {
    font-size: x-large;
}

caption {
    text-align: left;
}

th {
    background: rgba(255, 225, 225);
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

th:first-of-type, td:first-of-type {
    left: 0;
    position: sticky;
}

th:first-of-type {
    z-index: 2;
}

td:first-of-type {
    background: rgba(225, 255, 225);
    z-index: 1;
}

th, td p {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

td p {
    margin-top: 0;
}

td p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

th, td {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <table>
        <caption>Caption</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</th>
                <th>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</th>
                <th>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try setting `position: sticky` on the `caption` element?

Comment: Yes. It gives *some* effect, but it's too ugly: https://jsfiddle.net/zs7Ldhea/

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include it in the list of things you've tried, or you'll get answers (like the one you've gotten) that just do that.

Comment: Previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57442166/scrollable-table-with-first-column-and-first-row-pinned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

table {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

caption, th, p {
    font-size: x-large;
}

caption {
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    margin-top: -68px;
    display: table-header-group;
}

th {
    background: rgba(255, 225, 225);
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

th:first-of-type, td:first-of-type {
    left: 0;
    position: sticky;
}

th:first-of-type {
    z-index: 2;
}

td:first-of-type {
    background: rgba(225, 255, 225);
    z-index: 1;
}

th, td p {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

td p {
    margin-top: 0;
}

td p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

th, td {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
<p>paragraph 4</p>
<p>paragraph 5</p>
<div class="outer">
<div class="wrapper">
    <table>
        <caption>Caption</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</th>
                <th>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</th>
                <th>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

This is what you want to achieve (works in Chrome and safari)
Now it is working

Comment: To make the caption absolute positioned is not a good solution, because that element is taken out of the normal render flow, so if the table changes its size or gets moved to another position on the screen, it will be necessary to relocate the caption as well. This solution will not be friendly with other devices either.

Answer (score 1):

Improved version of Rishikesh Pal's answer.

- CSS is now improved over my original code: added support for text wrap and narrow tables.
- The caption-related margins are now calculated through jQuery, instead of being hard-coded.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.scrollable').each(function() {
            var caption = $(this).find('caption');
            var th = $(this).find('th');
            var captionHeight = caption.outerHeight(true);
            var thHeight = th.outerHeight();
            var totalHeight = captionHeight + thHeight;
            caption.css({marginTop: '-' + totalHeight + 'px'});
            $(this).css({marginTop: 'calc(' + captionHeight + 'px' + ' + 1em)'});
        });
    });
</script>

<style>
    body {
        margin: auto;
        width: 25em;
    }

    .scrollable {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        max-height: 15em;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    .scrollable table {
        border-spacing: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        min-width: 100%;
        width: max-content;
    }

    .scrollable caption {
        font-size: smaller;
        padding-bottom: 0.5em;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: left;
        width: 25em;
        z-index: 3;
    }

    .scrollable th, .scrollable td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
        max-width: 10em;
        padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .scrollable th {
        background: rgb(255, 205, 205);
        position: sticky;
        text-align: left;
        top: 0;
    }

    .scrollable th:first-of-type, .scrollable td:first-of-type {
        left: 0;
        position: sticky;
    }

    .scrollable th:first-of-type {
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .scrollable td:first-of-type {
        background: rgb(205, 255, 205);
        z-index: 1;
    }
</style>

<p>Paragraph 1.</p>
<p>Paragraph 2.</p>
<div class="scrollable">
    <table>
        <caption>Table 1 aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa</th>
                <th>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</th>
                <th>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb</p><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="scrollable">
    <table>
        <caption>Table 2</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
                <th>Column 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2</p><p>Column 2</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3</p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="scrollable">
    <table>
        <caption>Copy of Table 1 aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa</th>
                <th>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</th>
                <th>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb</p><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Column 1 aaa aaa aaa</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 2 bbb bbb bbb</p></td>
                <td><p>Column 3 ccc ccc ccc</p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of a scrolling table with fixed headers and pinned caption.

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
   border: 1px solid #bcb6b6;
   height: 214px;
   width: 480px;
   overflow-x: auto;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

table {
   border: 1px solid #e7e9eb;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

caption {
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 4;
   font-size: 22px;
   text-align: left;
   white-space: nowrap;
   background-color: #bcb6b6;
   padding: 5px;
}

caption span {
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

thead {
   position: sticky;
   top: 37px;
   background-color: #bcb6b6;
   z-index: 3;
}

thead tr th:first-child {
   position: sticky;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 4;
   background-color: #bcb6b6;
}

tbody { white-space: nowrap; }

tbody tr { height: 30px; }

tbody tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #e7e9eb; }

th, td {
   font-size: 18px;
   border: 1px solid #bcb6b6;
   padding: 5px 5px;
}

tbody tr td:first-child {
   background-color: #bcb6b6;
   position: sticky;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 2;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <table>
      <caption><span>Caption</span></caption>
      
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Header column 1</th>
            <th>Header column 2</th>
            <th>Header column 3</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Quamquam philosophiae quidem</td>
            <td>Ego autem quem timeam lectorem</td>
            <td>te enim iudicem aequum puto, modo quae dicat ille bene noris.</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Quamquam philosophiae quidem</td>
            <td>Ego autem quem timeam lectorem</td>
            <td>te enim iudicem aequum puto, modo quae dicat ille bene noris.</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Quamquam philosophiae quidem</td>
            <td>Ego autem quem timeam lectorem</td>
            <td>te enim iudicem aequum puto, modo quae dicat ille bene noris.</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Quamquam philosophiae quidem</td>
            <td>Ego autem quem timeam lectorem</td>
            <td>te enim iudicem aequum puto, modo quae dicat ille bene noris.</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Quamquam philosophiae quidem</td>
            <td>Ego autem quem timeam lectorem</td>
            <td>te enim iudicem aequum puto, modo quae dicat ille bene noris.</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Quamquam philosophiae quidem</td>
            <td>Ego autem quem timeam lectorem</td>
            <td>te enim iudicem aequum puto, modo quae dicat ille bene noris.</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Quamquam philosophiae quidem</td>
            <td>Ego autem quem timeam lectorem</td>
            <td>te enim iudicem aequum puto, modo quae dicat ille bene noris.</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Quamquam philosophiae quidem</td>
            <td>Ego autem quem timeam lectorem</td>
            <td>te enim iudicem aequum puto, modo quae dicat ille bene noris.</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```